# In JBoss deployed JSP files disappear from folders

Tags: jsp, jboss, jboss7.x

I am using JBoss EAP 7.2 .
My Java web application contains JSP pages in a WAR under an EAR. Single EAR deployed.

It worked for years on JBoss 6.4, 7.0, 7.2.

Last month, suddenly, I start getting issues were:

class: javax.servlet.ServletContext
method: getResource(pageUrl)

It returns NULL, on URL such as */preview/jsp/StartForm.jsp*

When investigated I see expected files does not exist in jboss/standalone/tmp, which contains the compiled JSP. And also jboss/standalone/data seems to missing some files (based on count).

The files still exist in the WAR, so this is not a build issue.

As far as I know nothing changed in my deployed procedure or my jboss configuration. But I assume something must have changed.

I will appreciate any idea what/where to check.

Answer (score 0):

File from jboss/standalone/tmp are deleted during server shutdown and its expected. But files will not be deleted from  jboss/standalone/data directory by jboss process. Check if someone manually deleted these files or if its deleted by any cleanup script/tool.

Comment: Initial check did not find any cleanup tool. I will check further.
for now I am looking for more ideas.